# MATLAB : How can I use static method inside another (static) method?

Tags: matlab, class, static-methods

I'm trying to define a class whose static method re-use already defined static method at the same class.

```matlab
classdef DesignOpt
   methods (Static)
       ToMatrix(vector) 
       Phi2G(Phi) 
   end
end
```

```matlab
function matrix = ToMatrix(vector)
if length(vector) == 6
    matrix = [0, -vector(3), vector(2), vector(4);
                vector(3), 0, -vector(1), vector(5);
                -vector(2), vector(1), 0, vector(6);
                0, 0, 0, 0];
    return
elseif length(vector) == 3
    matrix = [ 0, -vector(3), vector(2);
    vector(3), 0, -vector(1);
    -vector(2), vector(1), 0];
    return
else
    matrix = nan(4, 4);
    error(['<ToMatrix> ftn : vector.rows() = ' num2str(size(vector,1))])
end
end
```

```matlab
function G = Phi2G(Phi)

if(size(Phi,1) ~= 10)
    error(['ERROR: Wrong input size for PhiToG(): Phi.rows() = ' num2str(size(Phi,1))])
    G = nan(6,6);
    return
end

G = zeros(6,6);
m_Eye = Phi(1) * eye(3);
h_bracket = DesignOpt.ToMatrix(Phi(2:4));
I_moment = [Phi(5), Phi(8), Phi(10);
            Phi(8), Phi(6), Phi(9);
            Phi(10), Phi(9), Phi(7)];


G(1:3,1:3) = I_moment;
G(1:3,4:6) = h_bracket;
G(4:6,1:3) = h_bracket';
G(4:6,4:6) = m_Eye;
end
```

I want to use **ToMatrix** method inside **Phi2G**, but

Error using: DesignOpt.ToMatrix
Too many output arguments.
Error: DesignOpt.Phi2G (line 12)
h_bracket = DesignOpt.ToMatrix(Phi(2:4));

How can I fix it??

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare in your `classdef` that the method `ToMatrix` has an output argument. Here's a working example:

```
% @TestClass/TestClass.m:
classdef TestClass
    methods (Static)
        fcn1()
        out = fcn2() % Note: declare output argument(s)
    end
end

% @TestClass/fcn1.m
function fcn1()
disp(TestClass.fcn2());
end

% @TestClass/fcn2.m
function out = fcn2()
out = 7;
end
```